# We simply cannot write `<Foo style={ } ... />` in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I got a little carried away and wrote

```
<Foo 
  style={ } 
  ... 
/>
```

in the old days, we actually had `Foo` as a `<div>` usually, so that could make sense, to actually impose that style on the `<div>`. But later on, we actually had `<> ... </>` and it'd be not good to have ReactJS impose an element (such as `<div>`) containing all those elements, so the `style` line doesn't make sense in this case.

So in a way, we never could treat a component as an element and give it some basic HTML attributes? How would we set HTML attribute for a component?

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Do you mean why can't the braces be empty (because *"JSX attributes must only be assigned a non-empty expression"*)? Why can't we pass a `style` prop to `Foo` (...we can)? Something else?

Comment: more like the perspective of setting `style` or any basic HTML attribute for a component

Comment: But a component may render 50 `div`s or any other tags or no HTML elements at all for that matter. How would it know which dom element to apply it to?

Comment: that's what I said in the post

Comment: If you already know the answer, why did you ask?

Comment: more like the perspective of setting `style` or any basic HTML attribute for a component

Comment: I think the confusion here is that you think this used to be different before the introduction of fragments. This isn't the case. A component has always worked this way. You can pass whatever HTML attributes you want to a component, but within that component YOU must attach it to a DOM element, it is not done automatically (for the reasons listed above). There's nothing wrong with passing a `style` object to `Foo`, but within `Foo`, you must pass that prop to a `div` or another element that will use it.

Answer (score 0):

We could pass all HTML attributes to a React component as a prop and then inside the component's render function assign those props to the actual DOM HTML element.

```
const Foo = ({style}) => (
   <div style={style}> // assigning inline style to HTML dom element 
    This is Foo 
   </div>
)

<Foo style={color: 'red'} /> // passing style as a prop to Foo react component
```

You can use `JSX spread attributes` and make it more flexible so you won't have to specify individual HTML attributes as a prop. You simply spread restProps over your HTML element.

```
const Foo({ name, ...restProps }) => {
  return <div {...restProps}>{name}</div>;
}
```

Now you can pass DOM attributes to Foo and they'll be passed through to `div`.

```
<Foo 
 name="This is Foo"
 className="foo-class"
 id="my-foo"
 style="color: red"
/>
```

When you use `<> ... </>` this is a shorthand of `<React.Fragment>...</React.Fragment>` which lets you only group multiple list of children WITHOUT adding extra node to the DOM when it gets rendered.

```
 return (
    <>
      <Foo />
      <Foo />
      <Foo />
    </>
  );
```

This will render as

```
<div>This is Foo</div>
<div>This is Foo</div>
<div>This is Foo</div>
```

so if you find yourself need to pass a HTML attribute to `<>...</>` you can simply change react fragment to a `<div>...</div>` or `<span>...</span>` or other proper HTML elements and set your attribute on.